# Using WordPress text editor to publish content

Tags: php, html, css

I can't publish anything through my homepage text editor in WordPress. I've looked at my css and the only thing that came up was that the page width was set at only `60px`.

So I set width and height to 100% but still nothing will publish. The page says `updated` but when I search for something I've published through it, like an image or some code, nothing displays in my source code.

So I've looked at my php and searched for

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

Which apparently controls (though not sure how) the homepage. I couldn't find it in header.php, page.php, index.php.

So now still nothing will publish and I'm wondering where would the Php be which dictates something is published when I press `publish`? Also, what what error would I be looking for?

```
<body class="home page- 
template page-template- 
page- 
templates page-template- 
template-home page- 
template- 
page-templatestemplate- 
home- 
php page page-id-28 wp- 
custom-logo cookies-set 
cookies-accepted has- 
sidebar-right">
<div id="page" 
class="site"><a 
class="skip- 
link screen-reader-text" 
href="#content">Skip to 
content</a>
```

Desktop [here](https://4309.co.uk)